# Let's get critical: Mar 2015 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [English Language Learners Stack Exchange](http://ell.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://ell.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Final Results

- [How to stress the importance of an object](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/51359/how-to-stress-the-importance-of-an-object)

**Net Score: 22** (Excellent: 23, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [What are the names of the verb tenses used in these two sentences?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/48370/what-are-the-names-of-the-verb-tenses-used-in-these-two-sentences)

**Net Score: 18** (Excellent: 20, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [How many subjects are there in this sentence?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/49903/how-many-subjects-are-in-this-sentence)

**Net Score: 16** (Excellent: 17, Satisfactory: 12, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [If my fingers were stung by fish spines, shall I describe it as "I got hurt" or "I got injured" or what?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/48451/if-my-fingers-were-stung-by-fish-spines-shall-i-describe-it-as-i-got-hurt-or)

**Net Score: 12** (Excellent: 14, Satisfactory: 13, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- ['A center of' or 'a center for'?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/51051/a-center-of-or-a-center-for)

**Net Score: 10** (Excellent: 11, Satisfactory: 15, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [are thought to work in... - already working or expected to work?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/51360/are-thought-to-work-in-already-working-or-expected-to-work)

**Net Score: 9** (Excellent: 12, Satisfactory: 11, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- ["What time is it" versus "what is the time"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/48175/what-time-is-it-versus-what-is-the-time)

**Net Score: 8** (Excellent: 12, Satisfactory: 13, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

- [I'm rather confused about Verb form](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/47891/im-rather-confused-about-verb-form)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 9, Satisfactory: 10, Needs Improvement: 7)

---

- [Could you simplify the "the instruction permit" in simple English](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/51171/could-you-simplify-the-the-instruction-permit-in-simple-english)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 18, Needs Improvement: 5)

---

- [A place, some place, some places](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/47892/a-place-some-place-some-places)

**Net Score: -13** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 12, Needs Improvement: 15)

---

Answer (score 4):

I had a hard time finding equivalent information through a search for many of the evaluation questions, even though my Google Fu is pretty good. Some of the questions asked here are so dependent on context that it's much more difficult to find an exact match than for a question from say StackOverflow.SE or SoftwareRecommendations.SE.

I counted the difficulty in finding a relevant result using a general search in our favor, and tried to look just at the usefulness of the question and answers as if I had managed to find it. How do y'all handle evaluating a question that is difficult to find an answer for with an Internet search?

Comment: Exactly what I did - And I see I'm not the only *other* who agrees with what you did.